# need help making batch file make batch file that already has code

Tags: batch-file

My problem is that whenever I try to get my batch file make a file named `resource.bat` with the code already in it, it fails. I've tried so many times.

```
@echo off
color 0a
C:\>echo This is a sample bat file > sample.bat
C:\>type sample.bat
This is a sample bat file
C:\>
```

Comment: A double echo sounds feasible.

Answer (score 1):

```
(
echo @rem This batch file was made by a batch file
echo @echo off
echo setlocal enableextensions
echo color 0a
echo exit /b
)> resource.bat
```

OR:

```
type BatTemplate.txt> resource.bat
```

BatTemplate.txt:

```
@rem This batch file was made by a batch file
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
color 0a
exit /b
```

OR:

Make 5 batch files.

cmd:

```
cmd /e /q
for /l %a in (1,1,5) do type BatTemplate.txt> resource%a.bat
```

script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions 
for /l %%a in (1,1,5) do type BatTemplate.txt> resource%%a.bat
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@echo off
(
  echo @echo off
  echo color 0a
  echo echo This is a simple bat file
  echo exit /b
) >resource.bat
```